# Does the MSDeploy Agent require IIS?

Tags: iis, windows-services, msdeploy

I use MSDeploy for deploying asp.net sites to servers with IIS. I also use MSDeploy for deploying Windows Services to the same servers that have IIS.

My MSDeploy agents listen on `https://computername:8172/MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVIC`E

I'm evaluating if it's feasible to deploy a Windows Service to a machine that does not have IIS installed.

Does the MSDeploy agent require IIS or can the agent run without it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tested this in my own environment. MSDeploy can be installed without IIS. It works for deploying Windows Services to a machine that does not have IIS on it.